# uninstall fzaninotto/faker and change with fakerphp/faker via composer

Tags: ubuntu, package, composer-php, pimcore, coreshop

I have pimcore 10 & coreshop 3 running on Lubuntu 20.04 and Maria-db 15.1, php 8.0.8. (Run coreshop was only possible by using
`composer require fzaninotto/faker --ignore-platform-reqs`. coreshop renders the pictures in the shop to big, and it runs afer I deletet `'%coreshop.model.product_store_price.class%'` from `vendor/coreshop/core-shop/src/CoreShop/Bundle/CoreBundle/Resources/config/services/data_hub.yml`.)

**Now, I want to exchange `fzaninotto/faker` with `fakerphp/faker`.**
composer did not permit the exchange:

```
  Problem 1
    - fzaninotto/faker v1.6.0 requires php ^5.3.3|^7.0 -> your php version (8.0.8) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - fzaninotto/faker[v1.7.0, ..., v1.9.2] require php ^5.3.3 || ^7.0 -> your php version (8.0.8) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - coreshop/core-shop 3.0.x-dev is an alias of coreshop/core-shop dev-master and thus requires it to be installed too.
    - coreshop/core-shop dev-master requires fzaninotto/faker ^1.6 -> satisfiable by fzaninotto/faker[v1.6.0, ..., v1.9.2].
    - Root composer.json requires coreshop/core-shop >=3.0@dev -> satisfiable by coreshop/core-shop[3.0.x-dev (alias of dev-master)].
```

### Try's

I have tryed something, witch did **not** work:

TRY1 `composer remove vendor/fzaninotto/faker`

```
SYS: vendor/fzaninotto/faker is not required in your composer.json and has not been removed
```

TRY2: `composer require fakerphp/faker`

```
SYS: Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - fzaninotto/faker is locked to version v1.9.2 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - fzaninotto/faker v1.9.2 requires php ^5.3.3 || ^7.0 -> your php version (8.0.8) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 2
    - fzaninotto/faker v1.9.2 requires php ^5.3.3 || ^7.0 -> your php version (8.0.8) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - coreshop/core-shop 3.0.x-dev is an alias of coreshop/core-shop dev-master and thus requires it to be installed too.
    - coreshop/core-shop dev-master requires fzaninotto/faker ^1.6 -> satisfiable by fzaninotto/faker[v1.9.2].
    - Root composer.json requires coreshop/core-shop >=3.0@dev -> satisfiable by coreshop/core-shop[3.0.x-dev (alias of dev-master)].
```

TRY3: `composer remove fzaninotto/faker --ignore-platform-reqs`

```
SYS: ... Nothing to modify in lock file
...
Nothing to install, update or remove
...
```

TRY4: add in `composer.json`

```
  "require-dev": {
    "fakerphp/faker": "^1.13.0",
```

AND delete in `composer.lock` all of `fzaninotto/faker`

```
SYS: Removal failed, fzaninotto/faker is still present, it may be required by another package.
```

TRY5: `composer update --with-all-dependencies`

```
SYS: Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
  Problem 1
    - fzaninotto/faker v1.6.0 requires php ^5.3.3|^7.0 -> your php version (8.0.8) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - fzaninotto/faker[v1.7.0, ..., v1.9.2] require php ^5.3.3 || ^7.0 -> your php version (8.0.8) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - coreshop/core-shop 3.0.x-dev is an alias of coreshop/core-shop dev-master and thus requires it to be installed too.
    - coreshop/core-shop dev-master requires fzaninotto/faker ^1.6 -> satisfiable by fzaninotto/faker[v1.6.0, ..., v1.9.2].
    - Root composer.json requires coreshop/core-shop >=3.0@dev -> satisfiable by coreshop/core-shop[3.0.x-dev (alias of dev-master)].
```

Comment: Well, it looks like coreshop requires fzaninoto/faker. Since it is not a direct dependency, you will not be able to update it. Maybe try to see if a patched version of coreshop is available and if it uses fakerphp.if not, try to make a pull request. ;)

Comment: `coreshop/core-shop dev-master requires fzaninotto/faker ^1.6` - that means, you cannot replace it that simple. Why not open a bug report at the Coreshop repository?

Comment: Thank you very much. I have followed your advice [/pull/1706](https://github.com/coreshop/CoreShop/pull/1706).

Comment: **No solution**  change `fzaninotto/faker` to `fakerphp/faker` in `/var/www/html/ps/vendor/coreshop/core-shop/src/CoreShop/Bundle/CoreBundle/composer.json` and `/composer.json` 

    composer remove fzaninotto/faker -W

`php bin/console cache:clear`

system is running at first, side effects ....

Comment: I used Robbi's last comment, which helped but I also had to go into the composer.lock file and add a caret to fakerphp/faker so it would upgrade.  Now it's upgrading successfully.

Answer (score 5):

Try removing `"fzaninotto/faker":"^1.6"` under "require" in composer.json then run : 
 `composer update` 
 then: 
 `composer require fakerphp/faker`

Answer (score 0):

I am trying this

edit composer.json

```
"require": {
        "php": "^7.2.5|^8.1.12",
```

delete composer.json

```
run composer install
```

this is running for me

Answer (score 0):

just change the version of fzaninotto/faker to ^1.9.2 in composer.json file